# Can't deactivate constraint

Tags: swift, xcode

```
header.collectionView.snp.makeConstraints {
        $0.leading.equalTo(view)
        $0.trailing.equalTo(view)
        if needsToPresentTopBar {
            $0.top.equalTo(topBar.snp.bottom)
        } else {
            $0.top.equalTo(view.safeAreaLayoutGuide)
        }
        $0.bottom.equalTo(collectionView.snp.top)
        let height =  $0.height.equalTo(10)

        guard (currentCategory?.subcategories?.count ?? 0) > 0 else {
            height.constraint.activate()
                  return
               }
        height.constraint.deactivate()
        $0.height.equalTo(header.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize).priority(999)
    }
```

Hi everyone! I have a problem. I'm trying to deactivate constraint but it doesn't work. Once the constraint was set, the height is always 10. So how can I fix it?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Would you mind editing your post and typing out your code instead of linking to an image?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling `layoutIfNeeded()`?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, once you call `$0.height.equalTo(10)` your constraint is already set and there is no need to call `activate` to enable it, just like all your previous constraints on leading and trailing. Secondly, because all constraints are evaluated and added at the end of the block that you passed into `view.snp.makeConstraints`, calling `activate` or `deactivate` does nothing to the constraints. You must call these methods only after your `makeConstraints` block is complete, that is, outside of it.

```
let height: Constraint?
view.snp.makeConstraints {
    let height = $0.height.equalTo(10)
}
// Call it here
height.deactivate()
```

If you want to modify it, do not call `deactivate`. Rather, use `snp.updateConstraints` once your original `makeConstraints` is done.

```
view.snp.makeConstraints {
    $0.height.equalTo(10)
}

// Do not call updateConstraints inside of makeConstraints!!
view.snp.updateConstraints {
    $0.height.equalTo(20)
}
```

Aside from that, the way that your code is written is not the best way -- creating a constraint then check for a condition, rather than check the condition first before creating the constraint so that no unnecessary work is done. In light of that, I would suggest the following, which instead of calling `deactivate`(which is not going to work anyway), the constraint is not added in the first place.

```
header.collectionView.snp.makeConstraints {
    $0.leading.equalTo(view)
    $0.trailing.equalTo(view)
    if needsToPresentTopBar {
        $0.top.equalTo(topBar.snp.bottom)
    } else {
        $0.top.equalTo(view.safeAreaLayoutGuide)
    }
    $0.bottom.equalTo(collectionView.snp.top)

    if (currentCategory?.subcategories?.count ?? 0) > 0 {
        $0.height.equalTo(header.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize).priority(999)
    } else {
        $0.height.equalTo(10)
    }
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't work correctly because it is executed many times. The next time it is executed, the constraints from previous time are staying active. So, since I've set height equal to 10 it's gonna be always 10. So I need to deactivate this constraint.

Comment: Then use `snp.remakeConstraints`. That is the PROPER way to re-make constraints @user3438369